# Regex for xxxx.xxx.xxx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I need to validate a Vat number.

xxxx.xxx.xxx --> 0123.456.789 is a valid number.

I found a regex

```
^(BE)[0-1]{1}[0-9]{9}$|^((BE)|(BE ))[0-1]{1}(\d{3})([.]{1})(\d{3})([.]{1})(\d{3})
```

This validate the following entry: BE 0123.456.789.

But what i need is to validate only xxxx.xxx.xxx ( nothing else is valid , only this )

So 4 digits , a point , 3 digits , a point , 3 digits.

Also it needs to begin with 0 or 1 ( first x --> 0 or 1 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
^[01]\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$
```

Comment: Every answer here have been down voted at least once.  I think someone was just on the warpath.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because you just give the regex w/o explaining it. Compare with Oded's answer, which I in turn upvoted. I don't give rep for being the first, only for being the best.

Comment: @mmutz - you don't downvote for that. Add comment asking for explanation. If you downvote for a valid answer just because it is not detailed, then what is the difference between upvote and downvote? Just don't upvote my answer if you thought it needed more detail!

Comment: the tooltip over the downvote button says "This answer is not useful", not "This answer is not valid". And your answer was correct, but I felt it wasn't useful. Others think differently, including OP. That's fine. That said, I should have left a comment, yes. I apologize.

Answer (score 8):

Here you go:

```
^[01]\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$
```

Breakdown:

```
^      - Start of string
[01]   - Followed by a 0 or 1
\d{3}  - Followed by three numerals
\.     - Followed by a .
\d{3}  - Followed by three numerals
\.     - Followed by a .
\d{3}  - Followed by three numerals
$      - Followed by end of string
```

Comment: Doesn't check that the first character is 0 or 1

Comment: this question is a blood bath

Comment: Someone posted regex and explained each part of it - that like never happens.  Kudos to Oded for doing what everyone should be doing!

Answer (score 4):

If the patter you need to match really is: `4 digits , a point , 3 digits , a point , 3 digits. and begin with 0 or 1`

then try this:

```
^[01]\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the expression

```
^[0-1]\d{3}[.]\d{3}[.]\d{3}$

^     // start of the input
\d{#} // numbers repeated # times
[.]   // literal . (same as  \.  )
$     // end of the input
```

Comment: You're missing your second set of 3 numbers. And will that literal for a `.` work? I had always seen it done as `\.` but perhaps the grouping brackets makes it a literal character on its own?

Comment: @Charlie no, I'm not missing. And yes `[.]` is equivalent to `\.`

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Perhaps I read it wrong; I see it now regardless. You might want to edit your explanation notes to include the group twice -- I suspect that is the source of your downvotes. And cool tip for the `[.]`, I didn't know that one. +1 for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
^[01]\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, one way is

```
^[01]\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$
```

This is the correct regex if you want to allow any digits (incl. non-Arabic ones), as `\d` is the same as `[:digit:]`, which matches *any* character marked as a digit in Unicode.

If you only want to allow Arabic digits (and it sounds like you do), you should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`:

```
^[01][0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is exactly what you want to validate, you only need this:

```
^[01]\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}$
```

This does exactly what you said in the question: **0 or 1, 3 digits, point, 3 digits, point, 3 digits.**  Be aware that your regex in your question is more different from what you want than just the `BE`, however, if you found it in reference to VAT numbers then it also might be *more correct* or accept more common forms of VAT numbers.

Comment: @mmutz - Thanks (fixed).  But you have edit privileges - I wouldn't be offended if you used them (clearly a typo).